# Open CallKit screen from an active call in XCTest UI test

Tags: ios, xcode, call, xcuitest

I have a XCTest UI test where two devices establish a call using CallKit.
The CallKit screen is presented when the incoming call reaches the callee. Once he accepts the call, the main test app is presented and CallKit screen is backgrounded. This is the default behavior.

Is there any way to switch back to the CallKit screen ? It doesn't necessarily need to be a XCTest method, it could be regular SDK code that will just be called by the testing bundle.

I tried recording the process of opening multitasking view and switching to CallKit and this is the result:

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
app.children(matching: .window).element(boundBy: 0).children(matching: .other).element.children(matching: .other).element.children(matching: .other).element.tap()
app.otherElements["com.apple.InCallService"].tap()
```

But when the recorded code is run, the test fails with following error:

```
Assertion Failure: Failed to get matching snapshot: No matches found for Elements matching predicate '"com.apple.InCallService" IN identifiers' from input
```

Answer (score 0):

I never did it but you can try to use `XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.mobilephone").launch()` to switch back to the Call.

Comment: Thank you, I tried this, but unfortunately, it opened the Call app on the current active tab (Favourites, Recents, etc.) and not CallKit screen.

Answer (score 0):

Try to activate this screen by

`XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.InCallService").activate()`

or 
`XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.springboard").activate()`

Comment: Activating Springboard, backgrounds the test app and goes to Home screen. Trying to activate InCallService, fails with: `activate application '<XCUIApplicationImpl: 0x280a87390 com.apple.InCallService>' (current state: Running Background)`